# Contracts to rent hangars and positions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm designing an application to track the rental of position/s in hangars for planes. So, I have created the following entities:

Class Contract (Date from, Date to, Location, Customer)

Class Position (Integer sideOne, Integer sideTwo): Different planes requires different dimensions. In example: (3 meters x 4 meters) or (4 meters x 4 meters). I create one position per type and I assign several instances per Hangar.

Class Hangar extends Location: (String description) This kind of structure could have several Positions depending on size. In example: 3 (3 meters x 4 meters) and 2 (3 meters x 3 meters).

Class PositionInHangar extends Location: (Position position, Hangar hangar): This is because we need to rent "PositionInHangar", one, two or even all the Hangar.

I also built two repositories:

HangarRepository extends JPARepository
PositionInHangarRepository extends JpaRepository

Now, I'm needing to build the methods for the following:

Hangar/s by Id -> no problem with this.

Positions by Id -> no problem with this.

Positions by Hangar: I need to address every position as addressable units.
I tried to do in the following way:

```
public interface PositionInHangarRepository extends JpaRepository<PositionInHangar, Integer> {

List<PositionInHangar> findByHangarId(Hangar hangar);
}
```

But it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

```
public abstract class Location implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}

public class Hangar extends Location implements Serializable {
    private String description;      
}

public class Position implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String description;

    private Integer sideOne;

    private Integer sideTwo;
}

public class PositionInHangar extends Location implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    private Hangar hangar;

    @OneToOne
    private Position position;
}

@Repository
public interface HangarRepository extends JpaRepository<Hangar, Integer> {

}

@Repository
public interface PositionInHangarRepository extends JpaRepository<PositionInHangar, Integer> {
    List<Position> findByHangarId(Hangar hangar);
}
```

Comment: *But it does not work.* *Any suggestions?* provide the code that is *not working* and tell us why it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's some misleading when it comes to class naming. From your description I interpret that `Position` contains only dimensions (X and Y) and the actual position of a plane in a hangar would be determined by the class `PositionInHangar`.

As an example, `Hangar` A will have `List<PositionInHangar>` A1, A2 and A3 each of them having a `Position` with dimensions (e.g.: 2x3, 3x3, etc.). In your design you're trying to re-use (or have a fixed set of) dimensions.

If that's the case, I'd recommend to rename `Position` to `Dimension` (might be even worth looking at `java.awt.Dimension` if using the old AWT library is not an inconvenience) and `PositionInHanger` to `Position`.

You should end up with something like this:

```
public class Hangar {
  String name; // e.g. A
  Set<Position> positions;
}

public class Position {
  String name; //e.g. A1
  Hangar hangar;
  Dimension dimension;
}
```

Then, if you like to list all position by hangar, you'd just need to find the hangar/s that you want and do a `getPositions()`. Or you could go the other way around and create a `Set<Position> findByHangar(Hangar hangar)` in `PositionRepository` (maybe better since you'd be avoiding a possible Hibernate's `LazyInitializationException`).

Optionally, you could also include a `List<Position>` object in your `Contract` class to know which positions are "rented out" (which might or might not be a bi-directional relationship).

Comment: Excellent approach! Now I'm going to re implement the model.

Comment: I have implemented the model and it represent what I need. Thanks!